# Search array for <tr>

Tags: php

I have an array called $clantable. It is a table with over 175 rows.

Right now, the table is split up into line after line.  (PHP)

```
0=> <table>
2=> <tr style="height: 32px; ">
3=> <td> Stuff here</td>
4=> <td> Stuff here</td>
5=> </tr>
6=> <tr style="height: 32px; ">
// etc
200=> </table>
```

I'd like to search through the entire array for the

```
<tr style="height: 32px; ">
```

If I find a match, put it into a '$tr_array'. So I can come back to the '$tr_array' and then search from there.

I've tried preg_match, strpos , in_array, and array_search.

---

I want to it be like this

```
$tr_array[0] = 1; // line 1 of the clantable.  
$tr_array[1] = 7; // line 7 of the clantable is a new row. 
$tr_array[2] = 20; // line 20 of the clantable is a new row.  etc.
```

---

Thanks!

-Alan

Comment: Ok, so what happened with those functions that you tried?

Comment: Please show a sample of your desired output, it's not clear from your description what you want in the array.

Comment: Mhh I don't see the problem, you aren't looking for a strange pattern, you are just searching a string. I think array_search should do it's job quite well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "If I find a match, put it into a '$tr_array'", I assume 'it' you want an array in the following format:

```
 array(
      0 => '<tr style="height: 32px; "><td>Some stuff</td><td>Some stuff</td></tr>',
      1 => '...',
      etc...
 )
```

If that's what you want, you can join the array into a string and use a regex. This will produce an array like the example above

```
$results = array();
preg_match_all('%(<tr style="height: 32px; ">(?:<td>[A-Za-z0-9\s]*</td>)+</tr>)%', implode( '', $clantable), $results);
$tr_array = $results[0];
var_dump( $tr_array);
```

**Output:**

```
array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(72) "<tr style="height: 32px; "><td> Stuff here</td><td> Stuff here</td></tr>"
    [1]=>
    string(87) "<tr style="height: 32px; "><td> Second Example</td><td> Second Example Part 2</td></tr>"
  }
```

When you say "$tr_array' and then search from there", it sounds like you're doing HTML parsing / scraping. If so, it's unnecessary to form your tr_array. If you want, say, the contents of the  tags, you can do:

```
$results = array();
preg_match_all('%(?:<tr style="height: 32px; ">((?:<td>[A-Za-z0-9\s]*</td>)+)</tr>)%', implode('', $clantable), $results);
$td_array = $results[1];
var_dump( $td_array);
```

**Output:**

```
array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(40) "<td> Stuff here</td><td> Stuff here</td>"
    [1]=>
    string(55) "<td> Second Example</td><td> Second Example Part 2</td>"
  }
```

And you can continue to parse those results to get the contents of the td tags, or modify the regex to do it for you. However, I wouldn't recommend using a regex if you don't have to, since you can use PHP's DOMDocument class to traverse HTML, assuming you want the content of the td tags. It works on strings and creates a representation of the HTML in an easily parsable manner.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML( implode( '', $clantable));
$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName("tr");
echo 'Found ' . $elements->length . ' tr elements';
foreach( $elements as $el)
{
     if( trim( $el->getAttribute('style')) == 'height: 32px;')
     {
          foreach( $el->childNodes as $td_nodes)
          {
               echo '"' . $td_nodes->nodeValue . '"';
          }
     }
}
```

The above will output only the contents of the td tags.

Comment: Thank you btw. This is what I used :D

Comment: @AlanPHP - You are welcome :) - Since my post answered your question, can you please mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
function searchArrayText($clantable, $findText){
    foreach($findText as $e) {
        if(strpos($clantable, $e) !== false) {
            echo $e;
        }
    }
}
$findText = '<tr style="height: 32px; ">';
searchArrayText($clantable, $findText);


?>
```

Not sure if smartest method, but I use this.

Answer (score 1):

Using Alice's code... (+1)

I modified it to append into an array.

```
<?php
function searchArrayText($table_array, $findText){
    $return_array = array();
    foreach($table_array as $key => $val) {
        if($findText == $val) {
            $return_array['key'][] = $key;
            $return_array['val'][] = $val;
        }
    }
    return $return_array;
}

$findText = '<tr style="height: 32px; ">';
$tr_array = searchArrayText($clantable, $findText);

?>
```

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()                                                                              :/

Comment: Yes, because you can use $clan_table[0] and get '<table>'. $clan_table[75] and get '<td> Stuff here</td>'. It is a file I am scraping from a site. I put the "table" into an array called clantable.